# How to move Java 8 App Engine Flexible to App Engine Standard?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have made a basic **App Engine Flexible** Rest API that uses **Cloud endpoints** for authentication and uses Spring for the MVC framework.

Does anyone have any recommendations on how to switch this over to **App Engine Standard**?

I thought to change the  app.yaml file would work but I am a bit lost.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Modifying your app.yaml ***is*** the primary method of changing from flexible to standard environment, or vice versa. Barring any other special configuration for your particular project, this could be all you need to do.

**To deploy to standard environment, instead of flexible:**

Try simply commenting out the `env` property in your `app.yaml`:

```
#env: flex
```

By default, you'd deploy to the standard environment if `env` is not defined (is what my experience has been).

Beyond this, you'd have to look at individual properties in your app.yaml, as perhaps some of them may only apply to a specific deployment type. For example, `instance_class` is not a property used in flexible environment, whereas you can define that in standard environment. In theory, I would remove or comment-out `instance_class` if deploying to flexible environment, or just maintain a second app.yaml (e.g. named app_standard.yaml).

On a side note, one thing I did stumble upon recently (for Go, anyways):

For a flexible deployment, this failed...

```
# This failed for flexible deployment, but it's what Google docs states to use (no period in the number)
runtime: go111
```

Meanwhile, I had to define the period for flexible deployment...

```
# This worked on a flexible deployment (had to include the period in the number)
runtime: go1.11
```

However, for the exact same app, with no code changes, simply going to standard environment, I defined runtime version WITHOUT A PERIOD, as Google's docs say to do, and it worked:

```
# This worked for standard environment (no period in the number)
runtime: go112
```

Just illustrating how fine details in the app.yaml matter.